# Clicking on the Google Assistant icon of the google search widget doesn't activate google assisant

Tags: google, app-widgets, google-assistant

You know that Google Search bar widget that comes with the Google app? It has a Google assistant button click on which opens Google Voice Search instead of Google Assistant. How do I fix it? It used to work well but then I cleared Google web and app activity and that messed it all up.

Comment: Have you tried updating your Google app?

Comment: @daniel shakeel yes I have. It's on the latest version.

Comment: Please provide the complete android details.